# How to instant shutdown or halt in linux, without wait the system or apps or process close?

Tags: linux, bash, kernel, hardware, shutdown

I'm working in a custom linux distro, that automatically saves any file or write the hard drive to prevent losing data, Ok i need to shutdown the computer without wait close apps or close system, something like a hardware interruption for test the distro, or like shutdown forced like press the power button in a few seconds. But in this sircumstance called by bash or another programming language for linux.

I'm using this command:

```
halt
```

and

```
shutdown -s -n
```

but both does not work, the command `halt` waits to kernel close all services and got stuck in the tty console freezed, and the command `shutdown` do a normal shutdown waiting to all applications, services or process be closed. then they are not instant...

Have you any solution or alternative?

Comment: Would something like invoking the "*magic key*" combinations to sync & shutdown be sufficient and/or suitable as a solution? Question looks like you would want to power down ASAP. Is the `sync` command of any use here?

Comment: You need to tell answerers what system management softwares your "custom Linux distro" is using, not least because the `-s` option to `shutdown` there indicates that it isn't any of the widely used ones.

Comment: I **strongly** suspect their shutdown doesn't have a '-s' either.

Comment: Most architectures and/or system boards have a way to reset from software e.g. execute a special instruction, write a bit in a control register, assert an I/O pin - just work out how to do that for your system from the shell e.g. something like echoing a value into a file in /sys ... make sure you run `sync` before hand though, that may help you avoid completely stuffing up the system in some circumstances (which you will do eventually, if you reset the hardware this way).

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way to power off the machine from the shell is:

```
poweroff -ff
```

As specified in `poweroff`'s man page, specifying `-f` twice causes an immediate kill bypassing the init system and any sane process termination.  This will eventually, probably soon, cause you corruption problems as it prevents the system and applications from ensuring persistent integrity.

Comment: The question specifies a "custom Linux distro" and does not tell us what system management softwares are being used.  There are _at least five_ possible `poweroff` commands (runit's, the nosh toolset's, systemd's, van Smoorenburg init's, and upstart's).  Only four of them (runit's does not) have `-f` options.  In _only one_ does doubling `-f` mean something different to just a single `-f`.  And the fact that the questioner's `shutdown` supports an `-s` option indicates that _none of the five_ is the software that is in use, as none of their `shutdown`s has an `-s` option.